# Why was this post converted to community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I noticed that [a recent high-profile post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96933/why-did-git-get-so-much-hype-while-others-dont) had all answers put in community wiki fairly fast, by the same mysterious person which has not participated at all.

Is this a case of "Community Wiki Troll", or is there a perfectly acceptable reason?

Maybe Community Wikis are set for all answers once set for the question?

Answer (score 4):

The community wiki flag is set automatically once a question reaches 15 answers: this is to encourage collaboration on existing answers, as after 15 or so of them, it's highly likely answers are going to overlap.

Unfortunately, this automatic action is marked with a confusing message: the person who had the privilege of posting the answer that triggered the automatic conversion to community wiki is the one who gets the attribution.

Our sister meta site, [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), has more background on the [mechanics of community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), but you can rest assured that nobody has the ability to "troll" people with community wiki flags:

- Questions can only be converted to community wiki by diamond moderators or through automatic conversion
- Answers can only be converted to community wiki by the post owner, diamond moderators, or through automatic conversion

Comment: I understand, thank you for explaining. It is indeed confusing that the answer that caused Community Wiki makes the poster responsible.